# selecting specific fields in rails 3.0.1 by using find_by_id method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i would like to select specific field with alias names by method find_by_id , like 
using the following query

```
Model.find_by_id(params) # I am getting  all the table columns, 
                         # but i would like to have only some columns
                         # with alias names.
```

can  you please help me to achieve this?

Comment: This sounds like the same (or very similar) question that was posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547169/rails-find-method-select-alias-as-id

Answer (score 1):

```
Model.select('column_name as alias').find_by_id(params)
```

Unless I am misunderstanding your question.